# How to check if the active WIFI connection is a Hotspot (not mobile hotspot) in android?

Tags: java, android, url, https, connection

I want to check the state of the current internet connection of my device.

Until now, I used to try it with **HttpURLConnection** and *connect()* to the URL http://www.google.com and then handling the result via the response Code. For *200* it would be a stable connection. The response would be *3xx* if the URL redirects (for example to the Hotspot Login page in this case).

However, this worked fine on all the devices running Android **5.0.1** and lower. Since 5.0.2 I am getting 302 for all the states:

1. Connected to Hotspot but **not** logged in (this actually should return 302)
2. Connected to Hotspot and logged in
3. Connected to mobile data

My thought is, that it redirects to the **https** URL and therefore returning a false response code.

If I switch the URL to https://www.google.com, the last two states working just fine but if the device is **NOT** logged into the hotspot, it won't redirect at all (and therefore throwing the TimeoutException).

Here is my code (Note that it is part of an AsyncTask and actually in a Fragment):

```java
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Log.d(TAG, "checking internet...");


        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        //if an active network or mobile data is available and is connected
        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(TEST_URL);
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User_Agent", "test");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
                //tries to access a URL ("Google.com" in this case)
                Log.d(TAG,"trying to access " + TEST_URL);
                urlc.connect();
                responseCode = urlc.getResponseCode();
                Log.d(TAG, "Response Code: " + String.valueOf(responseCode));
                if (responseCode >= INFORMATIONAL && responseCode < STABLE_CONNECTION) {
                    //1xx = informational
                    //TODO

                } else if (responseCode >= STABLE_CONNECTION && responseCode < REDIRECTION) {
                    //2xx = stable
                    if (cm.isActiveNetworkMetered()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "active connection is metered");
                        return MOBILE_DATA; //when data is metered
                    }

                    return INTERNET_AVAILABLE;
                } else if (responseCode >= REDIRECTION && responseCode < C_ERROR) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Active Network is a Hotspot (or similar)");
                    //3xx = redirecting / hotspot?

                    return HOTSPOT;
                } else if (responseCode >= C_ERROR && responseCode < S_ERROR) {
                    //4xx = client error
                    Log.d(TAG, "client error");
                    return CLIENT_ERROR;
                } else if (responseCode >= S_ERROR) {
                    //5xx = server error
                    Log.d(TAG, "server error");
                    return SERVER_ERROR;
                }


            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error checking internet connection (Timeout)");
                return CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error checking internet connection (IOException)", e);  //return false for errors
                return NO_INTERNET;
            }
        }

        //return false, when there is neither an active network nor mobile data
        Log.d(TAG,"neither mobile data nor connected to wifi");
        return NO_INTERNET;

    }
```

So, my question is: Is there any workaround, that I won't be redirected, when I shouldn't?
Or is there even a better way to check, if the active connection is a public Hotspot (like Telekom Hotspot or similar)?

Thanks in advance!